# Backup tool for pulling files out of encrypted disks?

Tags: backup, encryption, luks, disk-encryption, cloning

Are there any backup/cloning/recovery tools that can pull files from LUKS-encrypted disks while dropping free blocks?

Something that runs from within the unlocked system and hot-transfers the files, or maybe runs from a bootable USB flash drive, prompts the encryption key, and unlocks the disk?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "dropping free blocks".

Comment: Hi, I mean leaving out unused space by being file system-aware and copying file by file (what `cp` does), rather than bit by bit (what `dd` does)

Comment: Example: 500 GB disk, 10 GB data. Copy only files => 10 GB backup. Clone bit by bit => 500 GB backup with 490 GB wasted space

Comment: Is it, for instance, possible to write a Bash script that somehow uses LUKS, prompts for the encryption key, decrypts the disk, then (ideally hot-)transfers all files to a backup drive, and encrypts the backup? Imagine - having a small script like this would be enormously handy. And if the partition structure is reproduced, the backup would even be bootable, i.e. you could just snapshot your entire system onto an external SSD, take it somewhere, and work from it on any host computer. You could carry around your entire (encrypted) workstation!

Comment: I'd recommend learning how to use rsync to copy files.  The fact that your disk is encrypted is largely irrelevant.  Whatever you use will need it to be opened (`cryptsetup luksOpen ...)` before operation.  Then all you're really asking for is a backup tool which operates on a file system rather than the block device.  Thus I'd suggest rsync as a command line tool which is well designed for copying file trees.

Comment: @PhilipCouling: Thanks a lot for this bit! I'm looking into `rsync`... Is it possible to use `rsync` to reproduce the entire disk incl. bootloader, partition structure etc.? I.e., if `rsync` operates on a file system, are these information (bootloader, partition tables etc.) accessible as "files"?

Comment: No these things aren't generally contained in the file system.  The one exception is the boot loader on a system using EFI instead of legacy boot.  That's stored as files in `/boot/efi/EFI` (on the EFI partition).  Typically those are less necessary though as you can usually get back to a working system without them.

Comment: @PhilipCouling: If you had a Linux system and just copied all the files to a backup drive using `cryptsetup luksOpen ...` and `rsync ...` - would this be 100% safe and sufficient to recreate the complete Linux system, including e.g. all security settings, network configurations (proxies, VPNs), user/group policies etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your disk is encrypted is largely irrelevant. Whatever you use will need the encrypted disk to be opened (`cryptsetup luksOpen ...`) before operation.

I'll also draw your attention to [e2image](https://linux.die.net/man/8/e2image) which may copy more filesystem meta data.  It only works with ext2,3,4 file systems.

Besides e2image, your only real option is to look at tools which copy file trees rather than blocks.  For backups, I use [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) copy files.

**Besides files, what else does your system need?**

Partition definitions will not be backed up with rsync.  Partitions sizes can be listed with with `fdisk -l <disk>` eg: `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and stored this in a file somewhere for safe keeping.

To boot up, you system will probably use UUIDs to know what file system mount's where.  These can be listed with `blkid` (`sudo blkid`).

If your system is using EFI (rather than legacy boot) then you need to also copy the contents of your EFI partition.

Comment: Many thanks, I feel like getting much closer to the solution! `rsync` seems perfect, since it can be used to update the backup or send it to a remote server. Does it fully support hot transfer, i.e. if I do `rsync` from within the running system, can I be sure that it will copy **all** files or potentially miss certain ones? And how do you restore your backup, especially everything outside the file system?